# Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: No route to host

Tags: node.js, flutter

```
void registerUser() async{
  if(emailController.text.isNotEmpty && passwordController.text.isNotEmpty){

    //creating user for backend
    var regBody = {
      "email":emailController.text,
      "password":passwordController.text
    };

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(registration),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
      },
      body: jsonEncode(regBody)
    );

    print(response);

    emailController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
    setState(() {
      warn = "";
    });
  }
  else{
    setState(() {
      warn = "Please Enter Email or Password";
    });
  }
}
```

this is my url code for api

```
final url = 'http://192.168.0.103:3000/';
final registration = url + "registration";
```

this my function of user registration and i am getting this error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: No route to host (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113), address = 192.168.0.103, port = 43740, uri=http://192.168.0.103:3000/registration
```